# Coding of Admin-Guest login section in an OS

Tags: linux, authentication, cmd, linux-kernel, operating-system

I developed an authentication algorithm for user authentication as part of my masters thesis and implemented it in PHP. I intend to know how can I implement the algorithm for operating system login, in which language (for linux)? also where the code will reside because it will not be click and run code it will automatically load upon the starting of OS.
Thank you and I hope no down vote in haste.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[PAM](http://www.linux-pam.org/) is the Pluggable Authentication Modules used in Linux. There is extensive documentation on writing new modules.

Comment: Some native language. Most typically C/C++ as it's Linux but any compatible language should work. Google `writing pam modules`.

Comment: thank you one more thing if you could help on the topic of extension of implementation of the algorithm on mobile.

Comment: I can't You should ask another question.